# Getting Android app content rating from google play

Tags: android, rating

I would like to get the installed app content rating which is shown on play store like 3+, 7+,17+ through programatically in my android app. I didn't find any api for this. I checked the ApplicationInfo and packageInfo class as well but no data was availale for this. Is there any way we can get the content rating of any app?